# How to convert asn.1 erlang notation into asn.1 value notation

Tags: erlang, asn.1

I want to receive aligned per encoded asn.1 message and decode it to asn.1 value notation. Is there any tools available? Erlang has support for encoding and decoding, and reading value notation from file, but decoding only gives erlang, not value notation.

```
'S1AP':decode('S1AP-PDU', [32,17,0,23,0,0,2,0,105,0,11,0,0,98,242,33,0,0,195,92,0,51,0,87,64,1,25]).

{ok,{successfulOutcome,{'SuccessfulOutcome',17,reject,{'S1SetupResponse',[{'ProtocolIE-Field',105,reject,[{'ServedGUMMEIsItem',["bò!"],["Ã\\"],["3"],asn1_NOVALUE}]},{'ProtocolIE-Field',87,ignore,25}]}}}}
```

How to continue with the above code. I would like to get the PDU like here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One#Example or below (taken from wiki site)

```
myQuestion FooQuestion ::= {
trackingNumber     5,
question           "Anybody there?"
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit, maybe add an example what would be the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include autogenerated hrl files that contain record definitions for your asn protocol data. They must be either in the same folder as asn1 source or in ../include. After that you'll be able to use record syntax `myQuestion#'FooQuestion'{trackingNumber=TrackingNumber, question=Question}` to pattern-match data.

Comment: I think kontulai is asking how to convert a decoded asn.1 erlang tuple, into the more human-readable asn.1 value notation, most likely for logging purposes.

Comment: Yeah, and that's why he needs records to write pretty-printer for them.